# How to push tags to remote git repository with PHPStorm?

Tags: git, phpstorm

I use PHPStorm IDE in my everyday development. It's pretty well integrated with many CVS. But when I start using git I've found that plenty of git functions are not supported. Or I just missed something. That's why I ask.

Is there any way to push tags (git push --tags) with PHPStorm?

When I run

> CVS | Git | Tag Files

tag is created and I even can see it in PHPStorm git log. But it exists only locally. Nothing is pushed to remote. If I try to make Push after tag creation IDE says "Nothing to push".

Comment: It is not **currently** supported by PhpStorm or any other IDE on IDEA platform (as far as I understand it was in previous version but then it was *temporarily* (?) removed for whatever reason): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77483

Comment: @LazyOne It's old question, so your answer is not up to date. :)
I just did it with PhpStorm 2021.3.2. Look at flu answer.

Comment: @PatrykGodowski That's an amazing conclusion for my 10 years old **comment**...

Comment: @LazyOne - it's still alive. :)

Answer (score 20):

### It's in the "Push Commits" dialog

> VCS | Git | Push → ☑ Push Tags

[image]

See: [Jetbrains Ticket IDEA-77483 - GIT "Push tags" missing from push dialog](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77483#focus=streamItem-27-1509368-0-0)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know PHPStorm, but a normal `git push <remote> <branch>` at the command line won't pickup tags. You need to issue either:

```
git push <remote> --tags ;# push all tags
git push <remote> <tag> ;# push one tag
```

Again, I can't speak to PHPStorm, but this operation is quite easy from the command line.

Comment: Well I'd prefer making it without switching to terminal, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[old answer, check most voted answer above]

You cannot do it.
But you can join a request in here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77483
The only possibility is command line and `git push –tags`

Comment: Joined! Thanks for notification!